# How to query stress and strain values in a specific element in Abaqus?

Tags: abaqus

I am trying to find easier way to get stress and strain values in a specific element in Abaqus.
Does anyone know how to do it? Is it possible to do with Query?

Thanks

Comment: sure, query, probe values...

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I used query tool -> probe values